# How to subtract the content of a column of two rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

[image: MY table]

and I want to return the difference between the two rows

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless a column specifies the ordering.

So, you can get the two values using `MAX()` and `MIN()`.  This should do what you want:

```
select max(nbaction) - min(nbaction)
from t;
```

EDIT:

Given your actual problem, you have multiple choices.  Here is one:

```
SELECT (SELECT nbaction
        FROM analyse_page_fait 
        WHERE operateurdimid = 2
        ORDER BY datedimid DESC
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
       ) -
       (SELECT nbaction
        FROM analyse_page_fait 
        WHERE operateurdimid = 2
        ORDER BY datedimid DESC
        OFFSET 1
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
       ) as diff
```

Comment: in fact I got this table using this query: SELECT   nbaction FROM analyse_page_fait where operateurdimid =2 ORDER BY datedimid DESC limit 2
So I can't use max and min because I want to have the difference between the last two rows of a table